# document.getElementById appears to return null

Tags: javascript

I'm making a html document that holds two number fields.

The user enters the numeric info then clicks a button that activates a method on a separate *.js* file. The issue I'm running into is that every time you enter the data and press the button it returns the data as `NULL`.

Here is what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Retirement calculation page!</h1>
<p class="a">Enter the information below to find out how much money you will have for retirement</p>

<form name="form1">
        Enter Age: <input type ="number" name="age1" min="1" max="125">
</form>
<form name="form2">
        Enter Contribution amount: <input type="number" name="cont1">
</form>
<button onclick="rFunction()">Submit</button>
<script src="retirement.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the method in the *.js* file.

```
function rFunction()
{
        var age = document.getElementById("age1");
        var cont = document.getElementById("cont1");

        document.write("Age = " + age );
        document.write("Cont = " + cont );

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use `getElementById`, but none of your elements actually have ids.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @FelixKling: not a duplicate, but a simple error.

Comment: Well, one of the reasons I cover is that there is no element with such an ID in the document, which is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't applying an ID to any field, and when you look for the value you'd find a DOM object, but you need the value. Change the HTML like this:

```
<form name="form1">
        Enter Age: <input type ="number" id="age1" name="age1" min="1" max="125">
        Enter Contribution amount: <input type="number" id="cont1" name="cont1">
</form>
<button onclick="rFunction()">Submit</button>
```

And modify your JS like this:

```
    var age = document.getElementById("age1").value;
    var cont = document.getElementById("cont1").value;
```

BTW - you don't need two form declarations.

Comment: Nice catch with the form decs.  That would definitely cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the name attribute with an Id attribute:

```
<form name="form1">
        Enter Age: <input type ="number" id="age1" name="age1" min="1" max="125">
</form>
<form name="form2">
        Enter Contribution amount: <input type="number" id="cont1" name="cont1">
```

This will allow you to get an element by its id (`getElementById`).

Comment: Perhaps, for this example, but `id` and `name` are different things. Omitting the `name` attribute will mean any data won't be submitted to a form handler.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
name="age1"
```

When you should be using

```
id="age1"
```

It's called getElementById.